# How to graph the following type of functions and discuss its differentiability:

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I am having trouble in graphing a particular type of functions where a function is divided piecewise, and for some pieces we have to be draw maximum part and for some we have to draw minimum part, for example,

Graph $g(x)$: $$
\text { Let } f(x)=x^{2}-2|x| \text { and } g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\min \{f(t)\}, & -2 \leq t< 0, & -2 \leq x<0 \\
\max \{f(t)\}, & 0 \leq t \leq 2, & 0 \leq x \leq 2 \\
f(x) & x>2
\end{array}\right.
$$

Can anyone explain the concepts behind graphing such type of functions?

PS: Please provide a source for theory of graphing such type of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is find $\min\{f(t)\}$ on $-2 \leq t < 0$ and $\max\{f(t)\}$ on $0 \leq t \leq 2$. Let's call these quantities $m$ and $M$ respectively. Among other methods, let's graph $f$ to find $m$ and $M$ (since the question is interested in graphing). Below is a graph of $f$ (I used Desmos for the graphing):

[image]

We quickly see $m = -1$ and $M = 0$. Using this information, the definition of $g(x)$ becomes:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & -2 \leq x < 0, \\
0 & 0 \leq x \leq 2, \\
f(x) & x > 2.
\end{cases}
$$
This definition is easier to visualize (we have eliminated the parameter $t$), and graphing this, we have:

[image]

(sorry if the blue lines are a bit hard to see)

Comment: Click on the images to expand if you are having trouble seeing them